# Error while trying to install sklearn from Pycharm | arrayobject.h cannot be absolute

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, installation

Complete error statement:

> ValueError: path '/home/andy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h' cannot be absolute

I have installed Scipy and numpy (mkl) version by downloading the compiled wheel files from this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then installing it from the cmd using `pip`.

I'm more of a python noob, my focus is primarily machine learning. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered today a similar problem.

Do you use Python 3.6 (Latest version)?

If you do, you might consider downgrading (reinstalling actually) to Python 3.5.. apparently, **sklearn** has few problems supporting Python 3.6 at the moment.

Comment: Damn! I am using python 3.6! Let me change that.

Comment: same problem here... already wasted so much time for fixing basetsd.h error by knowing that they needed win10 sdk for vc 2015, and now this :(

Answer (score 5):

This is an error due to absolute paths to include files being found in the source, which cannot be automatically converted by distutils to the correct system path when compiling on windows.

The easiest way to fix this particular issue is to add a few lines of code to "util.py" in PYTHONPATH\lib\distutils\util.py.  Add to the beginning of the function "convert_path"..

```
if pathname.startswith('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/'):
        paths = pathname.split('/')
        return 'C:\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\include\\numpy\\'+paths[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks!! Why does this even happen, should this be reported as an issue somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I also installed NumPy and SciPy from [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) and got the same error when trying to install scikit-learn from PyPI. Installation scikit-learn from [the same link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also installed Numpy-MKL following this link before and came across the same problem when installing scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2):

hmm..maybe it wants a relative path i.e. `../include/numpy/` and not the absolute path which contains `../arrayobject.h`