# Installing Python Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running the command "pip3 install scikit-learn", and the command prompt spits out the following error:

```
reading manifest file 'scikit_learn.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l0z1x7if\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 270, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l0z1x7if\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 266, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
    return distutils_install.run(self)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 557, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_egg_info.py", line 34, in run
    self.run_command('egg_info')
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 19, in run
    _egg_info.run(self)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 279, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 533, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 569, in add_defaults
    self.read_manifest()
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 201, in read_manifest
    self.filelist.append(line)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 475, in append
    path = convert_path(item)
  File "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\util.py", line 125, in convert_path
    raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname)
ValueError: path '/home/andy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h' cannot be absolute
Command "c:\users\nathanholt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NATHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-l0z1x7if\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7iz3ig6v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l0z1x7if\scikit-learn\"
```

I know my numpy+MKL and Scipy are both up to date, along with my C++ Redistributable. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Error while trying to install sklearn from Pycharm | arrayobject.h cannot be absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360126/error-while-trying-to-install-sklearn-from-pycharm-arrayobject-h-cannot-be-abs) -- "Python 3.6 (Latest version) is not yet supported, you might consider downgrading (reinstalling actually) to Python 3.5.. apparently, sklearn has few problems supporting Python 3.6 at the moment."

Answer (score 0):

Install it from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . If you use python 3.6 and win64 download `scikit_umfpack‑0.2.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` this one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `Anaconda`? https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows
After installing anaconda you can create a virtual environment with conda:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.5`

After that you will activate the evn

`source activate myenv
(myenv)$ conda install scikit-learn`

This works for me